# Annotations and SimpleFormController

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations

help me pls I used in my project .xml and simpleformcontroller then i added `<mvc:annotation-driven>` and controller which using @requestmapping, now controller with request mapping works fine, but all pages which uses simpleformcontroller doesnt work? can i fix it? thanks
this dont work

```
<bean name="/countrylist.html" class="com.mycompany.controller.controller.CountryController"/>
<bean name="/citylist.html" class="com.mycompany.controller.controller.CityController"/>

<bean name="/addcity.html" class="com.mycompany.controller.controller.AddCityController">
    <property name="commandClass" value="com.mycompany.model.domain.City"/>
    <property name="formView" value="addcity"/>
    <property name="successView" value="citylist.html"/>
</bean>
<bean name="/addcountry.html" class="com.mycompany.controller.controller.AddCountryController">
    <property name="commandClass" value="com.mycompany.model.domain.Country"/>
    <property name="formView" value="addcountry"/>
    <property name="successView" value="countrylist.html"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you tell exactly what you are using now: Annotaions or xml for controller mapping?

Comment: Im using both. And have a problem that annotation controller works and xml controllers doesnt. I cant use it both? Any fix for using both?

Comment: If you define anything in xml config file that will override your corresponding  annotation. What is your usage scenario? In what way you want to use both? Can you make it clear?

Comment: It is better to use Annotations or SimpleFormController?

Answer (score 0):

If you define a bean corresponding to  defined in your controller, then the annotation will get overriden by the *xml config* bean definition.

What to use- *xml config* vs *Annotations*: Both approaches have their own pros and cons. If you use *xml config* you do not need to re-compile your *Controller* and all the mappins would be available in a single (or multiple if you choose to do so) *xml config* file. While using *Annotations* makes your *Controller* better readable. But in this case you have to compile the *Controller* if you make any change in mapping or change any other attribute of the mapping *Annotations*.

Here are links to some resources explaining pros and cons of Annotations vs XML:

[Annotation vs XML](http://slashprod.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/xml-vs-annotations-in-your-config/)

[Why Annotations](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-you-should-use-springs)